Are there ferries between Spain and Morocco that charge per car and not per passenger?
I'll soon be hitchhiking through Spain and am thinking about making a crossing to Morocco.
When I need to use ferries I try to find one that charges per car because I can try to hitch a ride with somebody taking their car on the ferry. Hence the question: Are there any ferries between Spain and Morocco that charge per car and not per passenger?

They need to account for everyone who will go on the decks, I am pretty sure nobody does that

@NicolasFormichella It at least used to be common on all ferries between Norway/Sweden and mainland Europe. The car ticket simply included four or five passengers. If I remember correctly, you still had to specify when you booked how many passengers would be travelling.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Exactly. I was able to hitchhike a ride onto a ferry between Germany and Denmark once. They charged per car, so we could easily come aboard with a friendly couple. I don't know if they had to state the number of passengers beforehand, but if they had, it certainly didn't matter to anybody.

You can't travel in a car without a ticket that will identify you. The shipping companies in Spain charge both per traveller and car. You have to pay for your ticket and the car is added as a plus, depending on the availability.
I wouldn't recommend hitching in the car of a person you don't know. To me is the same risk as carrying somebody's else luggage at an airport, you don't know what is inside.
The companies that I know that operate the routes between Spain and Morocco are FRS, Transmediterránea and Balearia. You can get in this links all the information about the routes and prices. Don't forget to check promotions, even if they are charging you per car, an offer can lower the price of the travel

The answer reads a bit weird. Are some parts generated by a LLM (like chatGPT?)
The "Booking the travel a few weeks in advance would be enough." makes no sense on the question asked.
The companies linked are usefull, but that last sentence is weird again. "even if they are charging you per car" but he doesn't have a car.

Technically he didn't say that he doesn't have a car, just that he won't be using it for this trip. I agree that the answer is weird though.

English is not my native language, I am Spanish, I tried to write the reply as best as I could. I thought the main point for the question was more related to trying to save a bit of money in his travel, that's why I mentioned the offers and the problems of shorter routes. Now that I understood better the original question, you can't travel in a car without a ticket that will identify you. I wouldn't recommend hitching in the car of a person you don't know, to me is the same risk as carrying somebody's else luggage at an airport, you don't know what is inside.

Hey Bea - it sounds like "you can't travel in a car without a ticket that will identify you" is the answer to the question, so I would edit your answer and put it somewhere near the top, so the OP and future visitors will find it.

I am going to add it, thanks matt
